# PyOpenGL - passing transformation matrix into shader

Tags: python, opengl

I am having trouble passing projection and modelview matrices into the GLSL shader from my PyOpenGL code. My understanding is that OpenGL matrices are column major, but when I pass in projection and modelview matrices as shown, I don't see anything. I tried the transpose of the matrices, and it worked for the modelview matrix, but the projection matrix doesn't work either way. Here is the code:

```
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLUT.freeglut import *
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
import numpy, math, sys 

strVS = """
attribute vec3 aVert;
uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
uniform vec4 uColor;
varying vec4 vCol;

void main() {
  // option #1 - fails
  gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVert, 1.0); 
  // option #2 - works
  gl_Position = vec4(aVert, 1.0); 
  // set color
  vCol = vec4(uColor.rgb, 1.0);
}
"""
strFS = """
varying vec4 vCol;

void main() {
  // use vertex color
  gl_FragColor = vCol;
}

"""

# 3D scene
class Scene:

    # initialization
    def __init__(self):

        # create shader
        self.program = compileProgram(compileShader(strVS,
                                                    GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                                      compileShader(strFS,
                                                    GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
        glUseProgram(self.program)

        self.pMatrixUniform = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'uPMatrix')
    self.mvMatrixUniform = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 
                                                  "uMVMatrix")
        self.colorU = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "uColor")

    # attributes
    self.vertIndex = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "aVert")

        # color
        self.col0 = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]

        # define quad vertices 
    s = 0.2
    quadV = [
            -s, s, 0.0, 
             -s, -s, 0.0, 
             s, s, 0.0,
             s, s, 0.0,
             -s, -s, 0.0, 
             s, -s, 0.0
             ]

        # vertices
        self.vertexBuffer = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexBuffer)
        vertexData = numpy.array(quadV, numpy.float32)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*len(vertexData), vertexData, 
                     GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    # render 
    def render(self, pMatrix, mvMatrix):        
        # use shader
        glUseProgram(self.program)

        # set proj matrix
        glUniformMatrix4fv(self.pMatrixUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, pMatrix)

        # set modelview matrix
        glUniformMatrix4fv(self.mvMatrixUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, mvMatrix)

        # set color
        glUniform4fv(self.colorU, 1, self.col0)

        #enable arrays
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.vertIndex)

        # set buffers 
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexBuffer)
        glVertexAttribPointer(self.vertIndex, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)

        # draw
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)

        # disable arrays
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(self.vertIndex)            


class Renderer:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.aspect = width/float(height)
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)
        glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8,1.0)
        glutPostRedisplay()

    def keyPressed(self, *args):
        sys.exit()

    def draw(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        # build projection matrix
        fov = math.radians(45.0)
        f = 1.0/math.tan(fov/2.0)
        zN, zF = (0.1, 100.0)
        a = self.aspect
        pMatrix = numpy.array([f/a, 0.0, 0.0,               0.0, 
                               0.0, f,   0.0,               0.0, 
                               0.0, 0.0, (zF+zN)/(zN-zF),  -1.0, 
                               0.0, 0.0, 2.0*zF*zN/(zN-zF), 0.0], numpy.float32)

        # modelview matrix
        mvMatrix = numpy.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                                0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                                0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
                                0.5, 0.0, -5.0, 1.0], numpy.float32)

        # render
        self.scene.render(pMatrix, mvMatrix)
        # swap buffers
        glutSwapBuffers()

    def run(self):
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)
        glutInitWindowSize(400, 400)
        self.window = glutCreateWindow("Minimal")
        glutReshapeFunc(self.reshape)
        glutDisplayFunc(self.draw)
        glutKeyboardFunc(self.keyPressed) # Checks for key strokes
        self.scene = Scene()
        glutMainLoop()

glutInit(sys.argv)
prog = Renderer()
prog.run()
```

When I use `option #2` in the shader without either matrix, I get the following output:

[image: ouput when not transforming with mv/p]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try option #1 with identity matrices (which are invariant to transposition) to test if the matrix gets passed correctly?

Comment: Note that with using shaders the column vs. row order thing is no longer *that* important, as you can switch the ordering with the 3rd parameter of glUniformMatrix4fv ; setting it GL_TRUE will transpose the matrix you give it. Really handy at times.

Comment: @Nobody - yes, setting pMatrix and mvMatrix as identity works.

Comment: @datenwolf - thanks, I saw that in the docs. I don't understand why neither the matrix I have above nor its transpose works in case of the projection matrix.

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me (say it meets my expectations), so what do you expect and in which way does the result differ? (One error was there though: `line 127, in draw
    a = self.aspect
AttributeError: Renderer instance has no attribute 'aspect'`)

Comment: @Nobody - let me try this again and get back to you. For some strange reason I do not get an error for self.aspect - I agree that is a mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @Nobody - thanks for the responses. The code works now. I honestly don't understand why I was seeing problems before.

Comment: Voting to close as no longer reproducible.

Comment: Try [ModernGL](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of PyOpenGL